# Honda Jazz 2007 1.4 Dsi CVT

Tags: honda, suspension, bushing, jazz, control-arm

My Honda Jazz is in for 195,000 km service, Bosch service centre contacted me and said that my *Control Arm Bushings* are worn, but they need to replace the entire control arm as the bushings are not available for my Jazz. Can that be?

Please advise?

Thanks
Stefan

Answer (score 3):

That is the way Honda does a lot of their suspension parts. Take for instance, the part below. It isn't sold with bushings, but rather as a complete unit. This is the complete A-Arm from the front end kit for your Jazz (called a "[Fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Jazz)" here in the US). With this in mind, I don't think they are telling you anything out of the ordinary, though it does sound like it from the outside. This is what I'd expect to change if I were doing the work.

[image]